# 3D mesh unfold to 2D in runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, geometry, 2d, mesh

am facing a problem finding a simple solution for 3D mesh unfolding in unity

i have a situation where a 3D mesh will be edited in run time then unfold the 3D mesh into a 2D surface (reserving the scale) 
like in the example image 
on the right simple cube unfolded to squares 
and when move a vertex to make the cube on the left the result will be affected by the vertex position change

i found some apps like 
https://www.papercraft3d.com/upc/index.aspx
https://tamasoft.co.jp/pepakura-en/
but nothing to be integrated into unity

thanks in advance :')
[image]

Comment: What exactly is you question? Unfolding is an inherently hard problem. Take a look at [this project](http://masc.cs.gmu.edu/wiki/Learning2Unfold).

Comment: Could some of the techniques from uv unwrapping help you? I doubt you're going to find something ready-to-go in Unity, but there should be lots of literature on uv-unwrapping (the fact there is lots indicates it's not a simple problem and uv unwrapping can/does distort quads/triangles). There's also [this SketchUp plugin](https://github.com/alexschreyer/SketchUp-Flatten-Plugin). It's written in Ruby, but it shouldn't be too difficult to figure out how to translate.

Comment: If it's just the one mesh, you could just make it an animation in blender and use that.